# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/submitted from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I get this error any time I try to use the POST method of the API.

I have added `"proxy: "http://localhost:5000"` to the `package.json` file in the `client` folder.

---

`server/models/submitted.js`:

```
static insert(student_id, student_name, modules, callback) {
    db.query(
      `INSERT INTO returned (student_id), (student_name), (modules) VALUES ($1), ($2), ($3)`,
      [student_id], [student_name], [modules],
      function (e, res) {
        if (e.error) {
          return callback(e);
        }
        callback(res);
      }
    );
  }
```

---

`server/api/submitted.js` post method:

```
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var modules = req.body.modules;

  Submitted.insert(id, name, modules, function (e, result) {
    if (e) {
      return res.json(e);
    }
    return res.json(result);
  });
});
```

---

`client/App.js` method calling the `api/submitted` POST method:

```
  onSubmit = () => {
    fetch("api/submitted", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        student_id: this.state.id,
        student_name: this.state.name,
        modules: this.state.modulesSelected
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log("posted:" + res);
        this.setState({ name: "", id: "", modulesSelected: [] });
      });
  };
```

---

I have tried playing around with the `"proxy: http://*` in the `package.json` with no avail.

The `package.json` in the root folder has the following scripts to rund uring development:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "server": "nodemon server"
  }
```

Any suggestions? So far everything I have tried from other threads hasn't been working.

---

EDIT:

I fixed the issue by changing the `insert` function to the following:

```
static insert(student_id, student_name, modules, callback) {
    db.query(
      `INSERT INTO returned (student_id, student_name, modules) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)`,
      [student_id,
        student_name,
        modules
      ],
      function (e, res) {
        if (e.error) {
          return callback(e);
        }
        callback(null, res);
      }
    );
  }
```

I also added a `try/catch` where `insert` is called:

```
  try {
    Submitted.insert(id, name, modules, function (e, result) {
      if (e) {
        return res.json(e);
      }
      return res.json(result);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: error.toString()
    })
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at this simple lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: can you try with  `"proxy":"0.0.0.0:5000"` by placing it in package.json.

Comment: @SakoBu since he's proxying the request so that it's on the same host, I don't believe this to be a CORS issue

Comment: If you add a middleware before all of your route handlers which logs the request's path, does it ever get called? e.g. `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.originalUrl); next(); })` - and if it does, is it missing the `/api` from in front?

Comment: Note, try this with `"proxy: "http://localhost:5000"`. Also, was the backend indeed running on :5000?

Comment: There's also an error in `insert`, you probably meant `callback(null, res)` instead of `callback(res)`

Comment: @cubrr I am a little confused by "If you add a middleware before all of your route handlers which logs the request's path, does it ever get called?". Could you please elaborate on this? Like where would I add the code snippet?

Comment: Immediately after `var app = express()` or whatever your variable's name is.

Comment: I get `/api/submitted` in the console. @cubrr

Comment: Cool, so it reaches the server, so the issue is not in the `proxy`. Do you have an express [error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)? Did you fix the issue in `insert` which I pointed out in the comment?

Comment: @cubrr I fixed the issue with `insert`. I don't have an express error handler.

Comment: Add an error handler which logs the error. It could be that there's an error occurring which isn't handled.

Comment: @cubrr I get  `POST http://localhost:3000/api/submitted 500 (Internal Server Error)`  and `Uncaught (in promise) SytanxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools' Network tab and find this request. What is the response?

Comment: I found the mistake. I made a stupid error in the insert query. Sorry for wasting your time @cubrr, but thank you for spending your time trying to help me, much appreciated.

Comment: We managed to improve your code on the way so I don't think that's time wasted! Now that you have an error handler in the server, and you know where to look if a request comes back with an error of 500, you'll be able to find problems like this quicker in the future! :) You can answer your question with what the problem was and what you solved it with.